# Improper operand type MSVC

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++

Currently trying to emit a random instruction from a method but keep getting the error "Improper operand type".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#define PUSH    0x50
#define POP     0x58
#define NOP     0x90

auto generate_instruction() -> int {
    int instruction_list[] = { NOP };
    return instruction_list[rand() % (sizeof(instruction_list) / sizeof(*instruction_list))];
}

#define JUNK_INSTRUCTION(x)     \
__asm _emit PUSH                \
__asm _emit x                   \
__asm _emit POP                 \

#define JUNK JUNK_INSTRUCTION(generate_instruction)

int main() {
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
    JUNK;
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

However when I replace `#define JUNK JUNK_INSTRUCTION(generate_instruction)` with `#define JUNK JUNK_INSTRUCTION(NOP)` , the program runs fine. I'm unsure as to why it's not working when they both return the same value.

Comment: 0x50 is `push eax` (or in 64-bit mode, `push rax`), not `push imm8`.  So in the version with a constant arg, it's `push eax` / `nop` / `pop eax`, which is pretty much pointless.  It makes no sense to do this.  (And BTW, inline-asm can't JIT at runtime.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do.

`JUNK` expands to `JUNK_INSTRUCTION(generate_instruction)`, which will expand to:

```
__asm _emit PUSH
__asm _emit generate_instruction
__asm _emit POP
```

`generate_instruction` is simply the name of a function. The compiler is not going to run the function and replace just because you name it.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/emit-pseudoinstruction?view=vs-2017), you need to provide a constant byte value, like you do with the other two.

I think you are really confused with the concepts of run-time calls, compile-time computation and macros.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for the explanation, I was trying to return the NOP instruction from the function and use it.